# how to customize scroll color of tableview in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to set scroll style to pink color in tableview.please give any suggestion for that.

Comment: I was taking about setting scroll color,we can see that scroll normally of (by default) gray color in a table.

Answer (score 3):

but only available from this colors

```
    [tableview setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite];
```

Replace UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite to anything from this typedef.

```
      typedef enum {
            UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault,
            UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack,
            UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite
      } UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle;
```

Answer (score 2):

For the moment is not possible set a custom color in the Scroll. the only posible colors are white and black.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW5

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, Swift-3

```
 override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let verticalIndicator = scrollView.subviews.last as? UIImageView
        verticalIndicator?.image = nil
        verticalIndicator?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      }
```